# Apache running as nobody, but whoami shows "root" or my user name

Tags: php, apache, ownership

the problem is that I `used ps aux | grep apache` which says the apache is running as nobody.
But then I used `exec("whoami")`, it gives a different result: root or gt. It depends on the owner of the script. If the script is owned by `root`, whoami is `root`; if owned by `gt`, then whoami is `gt`.
I also checked httpd.conf, the apache user is nobody, group is nobody.

So could anybody explain this thing?

Thank you!

Comment: This may be due to the difference between "real" and "effective" user-ids. Compare the difference in return-values for [`posix_geteuid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-geteuid.php) and [`posix_getuid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getuid.php).

An explanation of "real" and "effective" user ids can be found at: http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node23.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using either cgi or fast-cgi ,

to be "nobody" you need to use mod_php (php as an apache module)

http://php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php

> When PHP is used as an Apache module it inherits Apache's user
>   permissions (typically those of the "nobody" user).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.attacks.php

> Using PHP as a CGI binary is an option for setups that for some reason
>   do not wish to integrate PHP as a module into server software (like
>   Apache), or will use PHP with different kinds of CGI wrappers to
>   create safe chroot and setuid environments for scripts.

And there is also SuPHP https://serverfault.com/questions/7589/how-do-you-run-a-php-script-as-the-owner

Comment: Yes, I'm using cgi. Thanks for the links!